# Assembly - a number to base 10

Tags: assembly, masm, x86-16

I'm trying to convert different bases to base 10(using Masm32; 8086). I already reversed the number I wanted ("text"), that is in an array. But now do not know what to do. Can someone help me, pelase?

This is when Invert the number:

```
COD1:
    mov al, text[di-1]  ; copies all the digits in the array
    mov es:[bx],al  ; to a new position: p2
    inc bx
    inc bx
    dec di
    loop    COD1
```

What should I do?

I tried to mul in the middle of this command, but the program crashes... I really don't know what to do anymore...

Thanks

Comment: Please describe more clearly what it is you are trying to do, and/or  post the code that fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you input a number, as text, which can be any of any number base, and you want to print out the decimal representation of that number?

Well, two main steps. General approach:

step 1:
convert ascii of any number base to binary:
initialise a register or variable, used as accumulator, with 0, 
iteratively read digits of input number, multiply accumulator contents by number base, then add digit value.
When done, accumulator contains binary representation of number.

step 2:
convert binary number to decimal  (or any other number base):
divide accumulator by number base. Keep truncated quotient in accumulator. convert remainder to ASCII equivalent of its numeric value. Reversely add to a buffer. Repeat. When accumulator is zero, buffer contains the string representing the converted number.

Note that you can avoid the buffering in step two, if all you want is outputting the number while converting it, rather than keep a string representation of it:  Recursively chop off digits, convert and stack them. Output stacked values when unwinding the recursion.